# Python - requests.get() return wrong html code

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to get the html code of one marketplace, I am getting the correct code for one category but for another one I am getting wrong result.

For this one

```
k = requests.get('https://www.skroutz.gr/plus-deals').text
soup1=BeautifulSoup(k,'html.parser')
soup1
```

I am getting the correct html code and I can process the data but for the following link i am getting less html code and there is now info about the product inside.

```
k = requests.get('https://www.skroutz.gr/c/40/kinhta-thlefwna.html').text
soup=BeautifulSoup(k,'html.parser')
soup
```

Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Please Wait... | Cloudflare</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots"/>
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" id="cf_styles-css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" /><![endif]-->
<style>body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>
<!--[if gte IE 10]><!-->
<script>
  if (!navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var cookieEl = document.getElementById('cookie-alert');
      cookieEl.style.display = 'block';
    })
  }
</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
    (function(){
      window._cf_chl_opt={
        cvId: "2",
        cType: "managed",
        cNounce: "84571",
        cRay: "724b4343a9c4152e",
        cHash: "fe638ea0b43499b",
        cUPMDTk: "\/c\/40\/kinhta-thlefwna.html?__cf_chl_tk=SyBbHJlHzS.xDpnxJdXeTIBNmKGSVY9Caf6BU5YW6xE-1656805606-0-gaNycGzNBz0",
        cFPWv: "b",
        cTTimeMs: "1000",
        cLt: "n",
        cRq: {
          ru: "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2tyb3V0ei5nci9jLzQwL2tpbmh0YS10aGxlZnduYS5odG1s",
          ra: "cHl0aG9uLXJlcXVlc3RzLzIuMjYuMA==",
          rm: "R0VU",
          d: "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",
          t: "MTY1NjgwNTYwNi45OTUwMDA=",
          m: "jz0GZxi5IN9yD0ZMzRvqHS7iO3DUD67nnR9aWi8akek=",
          i1: "yKKkb4Pl9MdAGpv3ff55sw==",
          i2: "0V/b+SP8SYiGm6Ql5jqhjg==",
          zh: "zMLZU0ozMixiusF5YQ59SCEM/iph9RYq7XDo619EjZk=",
          uh: "xaa5dII6Z3KyYGzGAu/zTXOfAYzLW3WlpO4dxW/Wc8c=",
          hh: "SbqW99632Mb3TCb6zbuLigmv9PVrnmEea13QmnYx5Y4=",
        }
      };
    }());
    //]]>
    </script>
<style>
  #cf-wrapper #spinner {width:69px; margin:  auto;}
  #cf-wrapper #cf-please-wait{text-align:center}
  .attribution {margin-top: 32px;}
  .bubbles { background-color: #f58220; width:20px; height: 20px; margin:2px; border-radius:100%; display:inline-block; }
  #cf-wrapper #challenge-form { padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px; }
  #cf-hcaptcha-container { text-align:center;}
  #cf-hcaptcha-container iframe { display: inline-block;}
  @keyframes fader     { 0% {opacity: 0.2;} 50% {opacity: 1.0;} 100% {opacity: 0.2;} }
  #cf-wrapper #cf-bubbles { width:69px; }
  @-webkit-keyframes fader { 0% {opacity: 0.2;} 50% {opacity: 1.0;} 100% {opacity: 0.2;} }
  #cf-bubbles > .bubbles { animation: fader 1.6s infinite;}
  #cf-bubbles > .bubbles:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: .2s;}
  #cf-bubbles > .bubbles:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: .4s;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cf-wrapper">
<div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" data-translate="enable_cookies" id="cookie-alert">Please enable cookies.</div>
<div class="cf-error-details-wrapper" id="cf-error-details">
<div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
<h1 data-translate="managed_challenge_headline">Please wait...</h1>
<h2 class="cf-subheadline"><span data-translate="managed_checking_msg">We are checking your browser...</span> www.skroutz.gr</h2>
</div>
<div class="cf-section cf-highlight cf-captcha-container">
<div class="cf-wrapper">
<div class="cf-columns two">
<div class="cf-column">
<div class="cf-highlight-inverse cf-form-stacked">
<form action="/c/40/kinhta-thlefwna.html?__cf_chl_f_tk=SyBbHJlHzS.xDpnxJdXeTIBNmKGSVY9Caf6BU5YW6xE-1656805606-0-gaNycGzNBz0" class="challenge-form managed-form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="challenge-form" method="POST">
<div id="cf-please-wait">
<div id="spinner">
<div id="cf-bubbles">
<div class="bubbles"></div>
<div class="bubbles"></div>
<div class="bubbles"></div>
</div>
</div>
<p data-translate="please_wait" id="cf-spinner-please-wait">Please stand by, while we are checking your browser...</p>
<p data-translate="redirecting" id="cf-spinner-redirecting" style="display:none">Redirecting...</p>
</div>
<input name="md" type="hidden" value="IwzwByLaPyYwh36ds_B76pH5fbjsm4NPLcrfOyVKp4k-1656805606-0-ATjH4PthZIQnlHja_TD2k3GIpJNvZi83t0ImbV0HYerX3pLXRLzqVYaRg_jJnr-ENIDFSkm2yG4ucsXrIj2kFquA7Ko4B40ctfjPfq93KAuO2HKoglP7QsaBaAwi3M-psOfnAbR48_o8kIFryXMdm6fJxGT8XpMh4LukCG0MavaJDWjYYiZcHHX82oSF7rx5_LnOgEkx0xkLtZZseZkhzqTfzzJ0S9wKzO9ZZdQMKxRxMIXWn36p3IezexUmZFlfbNtTFuETI0mWGSoTodXSiebeJasF-Ug2dnksRfhCQ1tsLun1XkVrbB5FauyBoa1Lh2-j6k3iW59xN6wsekKZcTrSaq03kn-bEod25lpVvQoe6u0wMmNYbBNWUtn4GER9CxWsDlUAXAwCp-BJAD-lHiJzAuBAmygbwFLRsoOcKOzUqtdQXNMX852hbTsSeTEw8a8bYxj-rHT4-d4zZDHGAw-dWKUAzVrtVSJLKlnRbknZ8BgT4FNnHF3Wwoo6JJxpoyYrrpMi4X27dgBkyymEQ0t1q7LXO_NSBxZIs33DM3hdiBMBHa69ZlFv92IKf-g6pnJnJj1QSlo5kVBTEd_wDswWTzLO6LmFz9VmMbGYTPPYbSFlP_b1VipLLI2DA4UVIOvb_7-alRtQjQQVZXFlkQYREd2J2EKtjzaOdMDKB6PgldFFeAOb97nCukF9UBBXHBAIATvR05AMvKt3LdBeL_3VDoyZe4Gnl8gbzlUTNP4OQ-o8ZEGcPC86WqWj5t2pSHw9XLxDFgR4IT7uYQOCY0cDmNe-BcbWz71ELBDGUXoyu7snXR_nMh6E3b87YNxVRSzeQ5JMrxajndJOfG_Oe0HSFF2SXFU_ahvhlY_GAY9TqexHH0pYzoVCJUtrkU8eTQ"/>
<input name="r" type="hidden" value="DUXMrZguXrr5SKxL5gb8bc9rgvwFZTJBMi4FVb0iz94-1656805606-0-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"/>
<input name="vc" type="hidden" value="28e85100a980cbce13a010a21dbc0851"/>
<noscript class="cf-captcha-info" id="cf-captcha-bookmark">
<h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1>
</noscript>
<div class="cookie-warning" data-translate="turn_on_cookies" id="no-cookie-warning" style="display:none">
<p data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="color:#bd2426;">Please enable Cookies and reload the page.</p>
</div>
<script>
  //<![CDATA[
    var a = function() {try{return !!window.addEventListener} catch(e) {return !1} },
      b = function(b, c) {a() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", b, c) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", b)};
      b(function(){
        var cookiesEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled)? true : false;
        if(!cookiesEnabled){
          var q = document.getElementById('no-cookie-warning');q.style.display = 'block';
        }
      });
  //]]>
  </script>
<div id="trk_captcha_js" style="background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/captcha/nojs/h/transparent.gif?ray=724b4343a9c4152e')"></div>
</form>
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
    (function(){
        var isIE = /(MSIE|Trident\/|Edge\/)/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
        var trkjs = isIE ? new Image() : document.createElement('img');
        trkjs.setAttribute("src", "/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/js/transparent.gif?ray=724b4343a9c4152e");
        trkjs.id = "trk_managed_js";
        trkjs.setAttribute("alt", "");
        document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
        var cpo=document.createElement('script');
        cpo.type='text/javascript';
        cpo.src="/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/managed/v1?ray=724b4343a9c4152e";
        
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.slice(0, -window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;
        if (window._cf_chl_opt.cUPMDTk && window.history && window.history.replaceState) {
          var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;
          history.replaceState(null, null, "\/c\/40\/kinhta-thlefwna.html?__cf_chl_rt_tk=SyBbHJlHzS.xDpnxJdXeTIBNmKGSVY9Caf6BU5YW6xE-1656805606-0-gaNycGzNBz0" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);
          cpo.onload = function() {
            history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);
          };
        }
        
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
    }());
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cf-column">
<div class="cf-screenshot-container">
<span class="cf-no-screenshot"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
<div class="cf-columns two">
<div class="cf-column">
<h2 data-translate="why_captcha_headline">Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?</h2>
<p data-translate="why_captcha_detail">Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.</p>
</div>
<div class="cf-column">
<h2 data-translate="resolve_captcha_headline">What can I do to prevent this in the future?</h2>
<p data-translate="resolve_captcha_antivirus">If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with malware.</p>
<p data-translate="resolve_captcha_network">If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network administrator to run a scan across the network looking for misconfigured or infected devices.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
<p class="text-13">
<span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">724b4343a9c4152e</strong></span>
<span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">•</span>
<span class="cf-footer-item hidden sm:block sm:mb-1" id="cf-footer-item-ip">
      Your IP:
      <button class="cf-footer-ip-reveal-btn" id="cf-footer-ip-reveal" type="button">Click to reveal</button>
<span class="hidden" id="cf-footer-ip">213.7.17.251</span>
<span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">•</span>
</span>
<span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
</p>
<script>(function(){function d(){var b=a.getElementById("cf-footer-item-ip"),c=a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip-reveal");b&&"classList"in b&&(b.classList.remove("hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){c.classList.add("hidden");a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip").classList.remove("hidden")}))}var a=document;document.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",d)})();</script>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->
</div>
</div>
<script>
  window._cf_translation = {};
  
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: requests doesn't execute javascript, which is probably what is rendering the results you want.  Perhaps try selenium instead

Comment: Since I never used selenium yet, how can I use it in my case @Chris ?

Comment: The selenium website has great documentation, including some starter examples that should get you where you need to be.

Comment: The page is protected with cloudflare, there is not much you can do other than switch to browser automation like playwright, selenium

Answer (score 0):

The website is loading data with an API. Here is the link: `https://www.skroutz.gr/c/40/kinhta-thlefwna.json?page=1`